# XHTML markup is incorrect near field

Tags: experience-editor

I am getting the following error only in Experience Editor :

[image]

The code associated is :

```
<div class="about-text">
     @Html.Sitecore().Field("{B5C0D199-7FFF-4B7A-A158-4D41DCAC81A0}", Model.Item) 
  </div>
```

I have also tried rendering the field using Field name instead of GUID, but still no luck. I even tried disabling **Is XHTML** global rule from **/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types/Rich Text** , even that's not working.

Can anyone pls provide me some assistance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the content of that field?

Comment: It's a Rich Text Field, so it contains a markup in HTML

Answer (score 2):

This is known bug from Sitecore, see link - https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0365101

Experience Editor/Page Editor may stop working correctly and not allow to edit item fields on the content pages that generate invalid HTML markup.

Above Sitecore link states -

A few examples of such markup:

```
1. Item presentation contains nested components that both render <p> tags, resulting in the HTML markup like this:
   <p>My <p>text</p> which gives trouble</p>

2. <div> tags being nested inside <p> tags:
   <p>This is a text block <div>but this one is a container</div></p>

3. Unclosed <div> tags:
   <div><p>Lots of data included here</p><div>But the outer div is not closed</div>
```

> Ensure that Sitecore items generate valid HTML markup. It is possible
> to use HTML validation in Microsoft Visual Studio or W3C Markup
> Validation Service.
>
> Note: Some of the issues with invalid markup were fixed in Sitecore
> 8.0 Update-6 and 8.1 Update-1. However, please avoid using invalid markup all the same.

You can also follow - [XHTML markup is incorrect near placeholder "header" Error, only for "header" key](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/xhtml-markup-is-incorrect-near-placeholder-header-error-only-for-header-key)