# XHTML validation error when trying to edit from experience editor

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I have an `aspx` layout file with the format

```
<a href "www.abc.com">                                                   
 <sc:Placeholder Key="footer1" runat="server" />
</a>
```

When I insert rich text rendering in `footer1` with anchor tag in richtext body I am getting `XHTML validation error` as anchor inside anchor is present.
Any way to handle that in `aspx` layout file or by disabling `XHTML` validation?

Comment: review this, if it can help - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28947/xhtml-markup-is-incorrect-near-field/28948#28948

Comment: No Gaurav its telling to make your html valid but i need to make it working with anchor inside anchor too.

Comment: Not sure about your sitecore version but this has some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452005/how-do-i-turn-off-xhtml-validation-in-sitecore

Comment: I'd rather re-think the markup, even if you can disable the HTML validator, why would you want to generate a non-compliant HTML?

Comment: Non complaint HTML is generated only in few case when i insert link in richtext. So i cant do anything on invalid HTML. What i require is to either disbale XHTML validation or add some specific condition for experience editor in layout file. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452005/how-do-i-turn-off-xhtml-validation-in-sitecore its not working.

Comment: You can find the article which says the reason for this behavior. [https://sitecoretroubleshooting.blogspot.com/2023/08/xhtml-validation-error-on-experience.html](https://sitecoretroubleshooting.blogspot.com/2023/08/xhtml-validation-error-on-experience.html)